# cmd echo inside loop is not working

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, echo

I'm trying to process the output of a program by running the following cmd command:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in (jps.exe) do (echo %i)
```

but this command does not print anything. However, when I run jps.exe (which is the [Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)) by itself, it prints the expected output. Why this is not working in the loop?

Note: I'm planning to replace echo %i with taskkill, but I wanted to see what output I'm getting before killing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the problem. I forgot to put jps.exe in quotes:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps.exe') do (echo %i)
```